# Node mysql2: Programmatically create triggers

Tags: node.js, prepared-statement, mysql2

I am using mysql2 2.2.5, and MySQL 8.0.31.

I receive the following error when attempting to create a trigger with mysql2:

"This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet".

The code:

```
connection.query(`
CREATE TRIGGER ${triggerName} AFTER UPDATE ON print FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 UPDATE materialized_views SET dirty = 1 WHERE viewName = ${DBHelper.escape(dependantTable.tableName)};
END;
`);
```

The complete error (with substituted values):

```
code: 'ER_UNSUPPORTED_PS',
  errno: 1295,
  sql: '\n' +
    '                                CREATE TRIGGER print_AFTER_UPDATE_MAKE_VIEWS_DIRTY AFTER UPDATE ON print FOR EACH ROW\n' +
    '                                BEGIN\n' +
    "                                    UPDATE materialized_views SET dirty = 1 WHERE viewName = 'scan';\n" +
    '                                END;\n' +
    '                            ',
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  sqlMessage: 'This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet'
```

Surely there must be a way to create triggers programmatically?

The query works when executed in MySQL Workbench, but not when executed by mysql2.

Additionally, I can confirm the newlines and tab characters aren't causing the issue.

Although this part doesn't matter for the question, the context is I am attempting to create an easy means of managing materialized views programmatically. You give the function a view name, and it determines the dependent views and creates triggers to mark the materialized view as dirty which will be periodically checked for a refresh. This is my last stumbling block...

Comment: ___This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet___

Comment: Most likely the query() method uses prepared statement by default to execute sql queries which triggers (pun intended) this error message. Mysql workbench does not use prepared statements to execute queries.

Comment: @Shadow Thank-you :). I figured as much, but my question still remains as to whether I can execute my query without a prepared statement, using mysql2 (ideally) or some other lightweight alternative.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't want to be snarky but yes, I can read... I understand the message, but I'm presuming there is still a way with mysql2 to not use prepared statements.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was being a bit snarky. But you would not have been the first person asking a question that didnt read the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I opted to execute it directly with mysql.exe.

Obviously this has some solution specific functions, but the idea is there.

```
async executeScript(sqlString: string) : Promise<Array<any>> {
    const scriptPath: string = path.join(__dirname, '/tmp/', crypto.randomUUID() + '.sql');

    await fs.writeFile(scriptPath, sqlString);

    const execCommand: string = 
        `"${globalSettings.mysql?.exePath}" ` + 
        `-h "${globalSettings.mysql?.host}" ` + 
        `-u "${globalSettings.mysql?.user}" ` +
        `-p"${globalSettings.mysql.password}" ` + 
        `"${globalSettings.mysql?.database}" ` + 
        `< "${scriptPath}"`;

    await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        ChildProcess.exec(execCommand, {
            timeout: 1000 * 10,
            killSignal: 'SIGKILL'
        }, (err, stdout) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERR: " + err);
                return;
            }
            //console.log("STDOUT: " + stdout);
            resolve();
        });
    });

    await fs.unlink(scriptPath);

    //TODO: Return printed results
    return [];
}
```